# Convergence of random vectors to vector with independent marginals when marginal distribution function converges at points of continuity

Tags: probability-theory, limits, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\xi_n, \xi, \eta_n, \eta$ be random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent, $\xi_n \overset{d}{\to} \xi$ and $\eta_n \overset{d}{\to} \eta$. Denote by $C(F_{\xi})$ the set of points of continuity of distribution function $F_{\xi}$ of $\xi$. Let $C(F_{\eta})$ have an obvious meaning. Prove of disprove that if
$$\mathbb{P} \Big( (\xi_n, \eta_n) \in (-\infty,x]\times (-\infty,y] \Big) \to \mathbb{P} \Big( (\xi, \eta) \in (-\infty,x]\times (-\infty,y] \Big) \quad (*)$$
for all $x \in C(F_{\xi})$ and $y \in C(F_{\eta})$ then $(\xi_n, \eta_n) \overset{d}{\to}  (\xi, \eta)$. We suppose that $z \le x$ iff $z_i \le x_i$ for all $1 \le i \le d$. I suppose that the answer is positive, but I'm not sure that my proof is correct and moreover, it looks that there should be a more simple proof.

***My attempt to make a simple proof (not successful).***

We know that $\xi_n \overset{d}{\to} \xi$ so $$\mathbb{P} \Big( \xi_n \in (-\infty,x] \Big) \to \mathbb{P} \Big( \xi \in (-\infty,x] \Big)$$
for all $x \in C(F_{\xi})$.
Hypothesis: if  $(x,y) \in C(F_{(\xi,\eta)})$ then $x \in C(F_{\xi})$ and  $y \in C(F_{\eta})$ . If the hypothesis is true then it follows from (*) that the answer in the original problem is positive.
Unfortunatelly the hypothesis is not true: counterexample is $\xi_n = \xi = 1, \eta_n = \eta = 0$, $x = y = 0$. So it's not a solution.

***Addition***

Theorem 2.2 from Billingsley, "Convergence of probability measures" looks like the answer, if I am right, because we can take $$\mathcal{U} = \{ (a,b] \times (c,d] | (P(\xi = a) = P(\xi = b) = 0 = P(\eta = c) = P(\eta = d) = 0)  \},$$
then $\mathcal{U}$ is a $\pi$-system and each open set in $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$ is a countable union of sets from  $\mathcal{U}$ so if $$\mathbb{P} \Big( (\xi_n, \eta_n) \in (a,b]\times (c,d] \Big) \to \mathbb{P} \Big( (\xi, \eta) \in (a,b]\times (c,d] \Big) \quad (**)$$  for all $(a,b]\times (c,d] \in U$ then $(*)$ is true. Hence it's sufficient to prove $(**)$ but it looks like it follows immediately from $(*)$. Am I right? And is there a more simple proof?

***Some more facts about problem.***

If $\xi_n$ and $\eta_n$ are independent then the answer in the original problem is positive.

Moreover, $(x,y) \in C(F_{(\xi,\eta)})$ iff $\mathbb{P} \Big( (\xi,\eta) \in \partial((-\infty,x] \times (-\infty,y]) \Big) = 0$, where $\partial X$ is a boundary of $X$. Hence if $(x,y) \in C(F_{(\xi,\eta)})$ then either $x \in C(F_{\xi})$ or  $y \in C(F_{\eta})$.

Billingsley, "Convergence of probability measures", doesn't contain the theorem in the form I need.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Let $\eta$ and $\xi_n\equiv \xi$ have identical non-constant distribution. Then, $\xi_n \overset{d}{\to} \xi$ and $\xi_n \overset{d}{\to} \eta$, however, $(\xi_n,\xi_n)$ does not converge to $(\xi,\eta)$ in distribution.

Comment: Perhaps, you forgot the assumption that $\xi_n$ and $\eta_n$ are independent as well.

Comment: @zhoraster Could you please explain why the condition (*) is fulfilled in this example?

Comment: Sorry, missed the word "if" :)